# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I have to solve a task where I have to show the specific location from all latitude longitude from database which distance is not more than 100 meter from my current location.

Here is my Main Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MultiDex.install(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        //etOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);

        btnFindPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        // db.addLocation(new LocationManager(1,);
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(1, "23.780551", "90.416380", "Gulshan-1"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(2, "23.780315", "90.418354", "Gulshan-1"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(3, "23.780472", "90.415093", "Gulshan-1"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(4, "23.780786", "90.422817", "Gulshan-1"));

        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(5, "23.776734", "90.425558", "Badda"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(6, "23.776538", "90.425601", "Badda"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(7, "23.776572", "90.425563", "Badda"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(8, "23.776911", "90.425595", "Badda"));

        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(9, "23.781436", "90.425442", "Pran RFl"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(10, "23.781293", "90.425583", "Pran RFl"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(11, "23.781307", "90.425280", "Pran RFl"));
        db.addLocation(new LocationManager(12, "23.781481", "90.425591", "Pran RFl"));

        btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mMap.clear();
                sendRequest();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {

                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();




        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
       /* mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);*/


    }

 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        // to get current location without click event code has to be added here
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }


        }
    }

    private double findDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (dist);
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }





    private void sendRequest() {

       LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        CircleOptions addCircle = new CircleOptions().center(latLng).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
        mCircle = mMap.addCircle(addCircle);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        List<LocationManager> locations = db.getAllLocations();

        for (LocationManager cn : locations) {

            finlat1 = Double.valueOf(cn.getLatitude());
            finlon2 = Double.valueOf(cn.getLongitude());
            String name = cn.getPlacename();
            double distance = findDistance(latitude, longitude, finlat2, finlon2) * 1000;

            if (distance <= 100.00) {

                LatLng venus = new LatLng(finlat2, finlon2);
                Log.wtf("venus:", String.valueOf(venus));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(venus, 18));
                originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mark))
                        .title(name)
                        .position(venus)));
            }

        }




        return;

    }



}
```

My db handler is: DatabaseHandler.java

```
package com.pran.vehicletrackingapp.dbhelper;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 11/30/2016.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import static java.lang.Integer.*;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "locationStore";
    private static final String TABLE_LOCATION = "locations";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    private static final String KEY_PLACENAME = "placename";

   // private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
    }



    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOCATION + "("
                + KEY_ID + "  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + KEY_LATITUDE + " TEXT ,"
                + KEY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT ,"
                + KEY_PLACENAME + " TEXT,"
                 + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATION);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // code to add the new contact
    public void addLocation(LocationManager location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID , location.getID());
        values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, location.getLatitude());
        values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE , location.getLongitude());
        values.put(KEY_PLACENAME, location.getPlacename()); // Contact Name
        //values.put(KEY_PH_NO, location.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOCATION, null, values);
        //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // code to get the single contact
    LocationManager getLocation(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_LOCATION, new String[] {
                KEY_ID,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_PLACENAME}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        LocationManager location = new LocationManager(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3) );
        // return contact
        return location;
    }

    // code to get all contacts in a list view
    public List<LocationManager> getAllLocations() {
        List<LocationManager> contactList = new ArrayList<LocationManager>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                LocationManager location = new LocationManager();
               location.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                location.setLatitude(cursor.getString(1));
                location.setLongitude(cursor.getString(2));
                location.setPlacename(cursor.getString(3));
               // contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(location);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // code to update the single contact
    public int updateLocation(LocationManager location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID , location.getID());
        values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, location.getLatitude());
        values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE , location.getLongitude());
        values.put(KEY_PLACENAME, location.getPlacename());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_LOCATION, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(location.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteLocation(LocationManager location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_LOCATION, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(location.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }

    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getLocationCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

But it has shown the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.pran.vehicletrackingapp, PID: 16019
>                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.pran.vehicletrackingapp.MapsActivity.sendRequest(MapsActivity.java:323)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.pran.vehicletrackingapp.MapsActivity.access$100(MapsActivity.java:46)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.pran.vehicletrackingapp.MapsActivity$1.onClick(MapsActivity.java:118)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
+ KEY_ID + "  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
```

should be

```
+ KEY_ID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
```

Comment: Your edit on the question completely changes it and renders this answer useless

Comment: Actually after posting it, I have found the problem.But the new error has been found. :)

Comment: In this case the best option could be posting a new question with your new problem